# Run the new "Convert to Layers" command in a Javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, photoshop, photoshop-script

Photoshop 2020 introduced the "Convert to Layers" command: **Layers** > **Smart Object** > **Convert to Layers**

It will insert the contents of the Smart Object into the active document. I want to use this command in an **Action.**

I recorded an Action to do just that. But then, using the Action on a Layer (not a Smart Object) I got an error saying the command is not available. This is a problem as It happens sometimes that the Action is executed on a layer or group of selected layers that aren't a Smart Object. Also, the Action Pannel conditional options do not have an option for "Active Layer is a Smart Object". Therefore I came down to the solution of using scripted conditionals (`if(isSmartObject){runCommand();}`) to execute the new command.

Now I've thrown a quick search into the *Photoshop 2020 Javascript scripting PDF* for "convert to layers" and even just "convert to" and I couldn't find it there. Then I tried the good old *Script listener* to try and generate the necessary Javascript to execute the command, without luck. The generated Javascript didn't do anything and the error message was something a long the lines of: *"This command might not be available in this version of Photoshop."*

*For now I have setteled for a script to check if the active layer is a smart object. If it is, it then executes a seperate Action containing the "Convert to Layers" command. This is an awful workaround I'd rather not have to deal with.*

*So long story short:* **is there any way to run this command using Javascript?**

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the command from ScriptingListener without issues:

`executeAction( stringIDToTypeID('placedLayerConvertToLayers'), undefined, DialogModes.NO );`

Note that since version 2020 (or 2019? don't remember) Photoshop has started to output a lot of trash in the ScriptingListener log (functions with `modalStateChanged`, `invokeCommand`, `forceNotify` and `modal` strings) — those cause Photoshop to raise exceptions and should be ignored. Maybe you had those in the code you were trying to run?